# How to Initialize Pointer to a Pointer to NULL Segmentation Fault 11

Tags: c++, pointers, null, insert, segmentation-fault

I am trying to implement a van emde boas tree but I am getting a Segmentation Fault 11 when I call my insert functions more than twice. When I tried printing the values in my insert function, I realized that the problem is when I initialize my clusters to NULL. I don't understand why that would be the case when I use a for loop. I also tried to use calloc but it gave me the same error. My code looks like this:

```
class vEB
{
    int u;
    int *m;
    int *M;
    vEB *summary;
    vEB **cluster;
public:
    vEB(int);
    bool member(int);
    void insert(int);
    void Delete(int);
    int min();
    int max();
    int* pred(int);
    int* succ(int);
};

vEB::vEB(int u){
    this -> u = u;
    this -> m = NULL;
    this -> M = NULL;

    if (u == 2){
        this -> summary = NULL;
        this -> cluster = NULL;
    } else {
        int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
        this -> summary = new vEB(subSize);
        this -> cluster = new vEB*[subSize];
        for (int i=0;i<=subSize;i++){
            cluster[i]=NULL;
        }

    }
}

bool vEB::member(int x){
    if (u == 2){
        if (m == NULL){
            return false;
        } 
        if (x == 0){
            return ((*m) == 0);
        } else if (x == 1){
            return ((*M) == 1);
        } 
        return false;
    }else{
        if (m == NULL) {
            return false;
        }
        if (x < (*m) || x > (*M)){
            return false;
        }else if (x == (*m) || (x == (*M))){
            return true;
        }else{
            int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
            int hi = x / subSize;
            int lo = x % subSize;
            if (cluster[hi] == NULL){
                return false;
            } else{
                return cluster[hi] -> member(lo);
            } 
        }

    }
}

void vEB::insert(int x) {
    if (u == 2) {
        if (x == 0) {
            if (m == NULL){
                m = new int;
                M = new int;
                (*m) = (*M) = x;
            } else {
                (*m) = x;
            }
        } else if (x == 1) {
            if (M == NULL){
                m = new int;
                M = new int;
                (*m) = (*M) = x;
            } else{
                (*M) = x;
            } 
        }
    } else {
        if (m == NULL) {
            m = new int;
            M = new int;
            (*m) = (*M) = x;
        } else {
            if (x < (*m)) {
                int currMin = (*m);
                (*m) = x;
                this -> insert(currMin);
            }else {
                int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
                int hi = x / subSize;
                printf("%d - %d\n",x, hi);
                int lo = x % subSize;
                printf("%d - %d\n",x, hi);
                if (cluster[hi] == NULL){
                    cluster[hi] = new vEB(subSize);
                    cluster[hi] -> insert(lo);
                    summary -> insert(hi);
                }else {
                    cluster[hi] -> insert(lo);
                }
                if (x > (*M)){
                    (*M) = x;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
}

void vEB::Delete(int x){
    if (u == 2) {
        if (x == 0) {
            if ((*M) == 0){
                m = M = NULL;
            } else{
                (*m) = 1;
            } 
        } else if (x == 1) {
            if ((*m) == 1) {
                m = M = NULL;
            }
            else {
                (*M) = 0;
            }
        }
    }else{
        int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
        int hi = x / subSize;
        int lo = x % subSize;

        if (x == (*m)){
            if (x == (*M)){
                m = M = NULL;
            } else {
                int nextMinHi = summary -> min();
                int nextMinLo = cluster[summary -> min()] -> min();
                int nextMin = nextMinHi * subSize + nextMinLo;
                this -> Delete(nextMin);
                (*m) = nextMin;
            }
        } else {
            cluster[hi] -> Delete(lo);
            if (cluster[hi] -> m == NULL){
                summary -> Delete(hi);
                delete cluster[hi];
                cluster[hi] = NULL;
            }
            if (x == (*M)){
                if (summary -> m == NULL) {
                    (*M) = (*m);
                } else{
                    int nextMaxHi = summary -> max();
                    int nextMaxLo = cluster[summary -> max()] -> max();
                    (*M) = nextMaxHi * subSize + nextMaxLo;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int vEB::min() {
    return (*m);
}

int vEB::max() {
    return (*M);
}

int* vEB::pred(int x){
    if (u == 2){
        if (x == 0) {
            return NULL;
        } else if (x == 1){
            if (m == NULL){
                return NULL;
            } 
            if ((*m) == 1){
                return NULL;
            } 
            return m;
        }
        else {
            return NULL;
        }
    } else {
        if (m == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (x <= (*m)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (x > (*M)) {
            return M;
        }
        int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
        int hi = x / subSize;
        int lo = x % subSize;
        if (cluster[hi] == NULL){
            int* prev = summary -> pred(hi);
            int* ret = new int;
            (*ret) = (*prev) * subSize + cluster[(*prev)] -> max();
            return ret;
        } else {
            int *newLo, *newHi;
            newHi = new int;
            newLo = new int;
            (*newHi) = hi;
            int minInCluster = cluster[hi] -> min();
            if (lo > minInCluster){
                 newLo = cluster[hi] -> pred(lo);
            }else {
                newHi = summary -> pred(hi);
                (*newLo) = cluster[(*newHi)] -> max();
            }
            int *ret = new int;
            (*ret) = (*newHi) * subSize + (*newLo);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

int* vEB::succ(int x) {
    if (u == 2) {
        if (x == 1) {
            return NULL;
        }else if (x == 0) {
            if (M == NULL) {
                return NULL;
            }
            if ((*M) == 0) {
                return NULL;
            }
            return M;
        }else {
            return NULL;
        }
    }else{
        if (m == NULL) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (x >= (*M)) {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (x < (*m)) {
            return m;
        }
        int subSize = (int)sqrt(u);
        int hi = x / subSize;
        int lo = x % subSize;
        if (cluster[hi] == NULL) {
            int* next = summary -> succ(hi);
            int* ret = new int;
            (*ret) = (*next) * subSize + cluster[(*next)] -> min();
            return ret;
        } else {
            int *newLo, *newHi;
            newHi = new int;
            newLo = new int;
            (*newHi) = hi;
            int maxInCluster = cluster[hi] -> max();
            if (lo < maxInCluster){
                newLo = cluster[hi] -> succ(lo);
            }else {
                newHi = summary -> succ(hi);
                (*newLo) = cluster[(*newHi)] -> min();
            }
            int *ret = new int;
            (*ret) = (*newHi) * subSize + (*newLo);
            return ret;
        }
    }
}

int main(){

    vEB *vEB = new class vEB(8);
    vEB -> insert(1);
    vEB -> insert(2);
    vEB -> insert(5);
    vEB -> insert(6);
    vEB -> insert(7);
    printf("%d\n", (*vEB -> pred(2)));
    printf("%d\n", (*vEB -> succ(2)));

    vEB -> Delete(2);

    return 0;
}
```

Is there a proper way to initialize pointers to a pointer that I am not aware of? Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: For an array of `subSize` elements, what is the min and max valid index? Please do some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) of your loop in the constructor.

Comment: What is your debugger showing? On which line the segmentation fault has occurred?

Comment: It is in the cluster[i]=NULL elements that it stops. My debugger only shows where it encountered a problem.

Comment: Here's a general hint to make it easier to debug and find/fix errors in your code: Don't write large pieces of code without testing. Start with a very small piece, build it (with lots of warnings enabled), fix build-errors and warnings, test. Once everything works, write the next *small* piece of code, build and test. And so on. When there's a problem (like a crash) then you only have little code to find the error in, and that makes it much easier to figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

In `vEB::vEB(int u)`

> ```
> for (int i=0;i<=subSize;i++){
>        cluster[i]=NULL;
>    }
> ```

must be

> ```
> for (int i=0;i<subSize;i++){
>        cluster[i]=NULL;
>    }
> ```

because `this -> cluster = new vEB*[subSize];` rather than `this -> cluster = new vEB*[subSize+1];`

> I am getting a Segmentation Fault 11 when I call my insert functions more than twice.

When you do `vEB -> insert(5);` the value of *hi* is too high and `cluster[hi]` is out of *cluster*.

Comment: I tried both i<=subSize and i<subSize but they still give me the same result and stop at the same time.

Comment: @Aciel the first error I speak is trivial to see but yes you have other , I edited my answer, I continue to search ...

Comment: @Aciel it is difficult to understand the logic of your program, then to find the reason of the next errors.

Comment: Thank you very much @bruno. I will try to take note of what you said.

Answer (score 0):

While the off-by-one error is bad, you have an even worse error: Possible infinite recursion.

In your `VEC` constructor you have a check for `u == 2`, but what happens if `u` is e.g. `3`? Then you would go into the `else` case, you get the square root of `3` which will be truncated to the integer `1`. Then you do `new VEC(1)` which calls the constructor with the value `1` (which is not equal to `2`), go into the `else` branch and get the square root of `1` which is equal to `1`. Then you do `new VEC(1)` (again!) and so on and on forever.

You need to check if `u <= 2` to avoid this.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a solution to your problem, but I hope it helps.
With some debugging I found that your problem is when you call insert(5).
The code that produces segfault is:

```
                if (cluster[hi] == NULL) {
                cluster[hi] = new vEB(subSize);
                cluster[hi]->insert(lo);
                summary->insert(hi);
            }
            else {
                cluster[hi]->insert(lo);  //here something is wrong with cluster[hi]
            }
```

I couldn't find out what is the answer, but if you put your code in an IDE and debug it, you have better chances to solve the problem because you understand your code better than me.

Answer (score 0):

My finding is the same as bruno's.  Here is a [live test of your code](https://segfault.stensal.com/a/5Gq42m9cx1og8LD1).  You can fix it and test it again.

=========== Start of #0 stensal runtime message ===========

Runtime error: **[out-of-bounds write]**
  Continuing execution can cause undefined behavior, abort!

```
-
- Writing 4 bytes to 0x8aaa078 will corrupt the adjacent data.
- 
- The memory-space-to-be-written (start:0x8aaa070, size:8 bytes) is allocated at
-     file:/src/new.cpp::54, 17
- 
-  0x8aaa070               0x8aaa077
-  +------------------------------+
-  |the memory-space-to-be-written|......
-  +------------------------------+
-                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
-        the write starts at 0x8aaa078 that is right after the memory end.
- 
- Stack trace (most recent call first) of the write.
- [1]  file:/prog.cc::35, 13
- [2]  file:/prog.cc::290, 10

- [3]  [libc-start-main]
-
```

============ End of #0 stensal runtime message ============